# .ajaxComplete with a datepicker change function : can't get inside the ajaxComplete

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a datepicker, with which I want to calculate a query as soon as the date is selected. I  am trying to use the .ajaxComplete, but I can't get inside it. Any idea ?

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
                $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
             });
</script>
</head>
<body>  
<div>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"/></div>
<div id="result"> Turnover: </div>  
<script>
    $("#datepicker").change(function(){
        var currentDate = $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
        $("result").ajaxComplete(function(){
            $(this).html("<p>Result here : </p>");  
        });             
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the (let's say at least one :-)) answer : I had nothing completed ! I added a button to have a complete event.

```
    <button class="trigger">Calculate</button>

<script>
        $( ".trigger" ).click(function() {
        $( ".result2" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to add `#` to the `result` like this

```
$("#result").ajaxComplete(function(){
            $(this).html("<p>Result here : </p>");  
        });
```

Comment: OK I did it, but still it's not doing anything when I change the date.

Comment: Ok. try it this way:
`$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
            $("#result").html("<p>Result here : </p>");  
        });`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Still not working. I also tried to pop-up an alert inside the ajaxComplete, and the pop-up is never appearing...

Comment: might be the library you're using is already binding ajaxComplete so you need to check that out..

Comment: The libraries link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script> ? You suggest that I change them ? With what ?

Comment: No no no... I'm saying that the library it self within the its code might be binding the `ajaxComlete` and then you also are performing `ajaxComplete` so that's why yours are not working. I'm not sure a 100% though. it needs more debugging. check the `firebug console` to see what type of errors are you facing here.